# Elasticsearch doesn't filter documents with timestamp against provided timestamp mapping "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"

Tags: elasticsearch, timestamp

I have an Elasticsearch index named "car" with a property name "created at" which stored the timestamp when the car object was created.

```
{
  "car_name": "sendrel",
  "brand": "toyota",
  "price": 12500,
  "timestamp": "2021-02-02 00:00:00"  
}
```

As the ES default uses the "yyyy-MM-dd", so the change the timestamp mapping by making a put request to the ES doc "car" following this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html)

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/car
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "timestamp": {
        "type":   "date",
        "format": "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I try to query in this "car" index with greater than timestamp, it gives me all the docs.

My query is given below:

```
query: {
        bool: {
          must: [
                 { 
                   range: { 
                            timestamp: { 
                                          gte: '2021-01-01 00:00:00' 
                                        } 
                          } 
                 }
          ]
        },
      },
```

I am new to Elasticsearch, so please provide the descriptive answers and also suggest me some blogs.

Comment: Can you share some documents and your full query?

Comment: actually when you put a mapping to es for a index, you also have to put other properties with timestamp property...other es will not recognize the index mapping...and throw error....i found out that whats my problem was....